# Terminal Text Output in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos

I've been reading through Objective-C for Dummies and I can't seem to find how to display text to the screen in a terminal application. A C++ equivilant would be `cout << "help me" ;` How do I display text in objective C? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to NSLog you can use C functions like puts and printf.

```
NSString *greeting = @"Hello world";
printf("%s",[greeting cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

It's sort of annoying to get a char* (aka c string) from an NSString but you can avoid the other stuff that NSLog adds to your output.  This more closely matches the stream operator from C++

Answer (score 1):

To display text in the terminal:
`NSLog(@"Hey StackOverflow") ;`